# Create a dropdown in SharePoint with values from a list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I need to create a simple dropdown in SharePoint site which takes values from a list in the same site. I don't want to go with forms or info paths, I would prefer creating it with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML to have something as the following - e.g. in a Content Editor WebPart:

```
<select id="MySelectId">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
</select>
```

Your JavaScript could look like this (using jQuery for convenience ...):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://<DomainName>/<PathToWeb>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<ListTitle>')/items",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
            $("#MySelectId").append($("<option></option>")
                            .val(value.ID)
                            .html(value.Title);
        });
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Within the `$.each` callback you can work with the items however you want - e.g. to fill your dropdown, etc.

n.b. If you need other fields than ID or Title, you must include them in a select statement at the end of the request URL using the InternalName as described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111473/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-reliable-way-to-retrieve-all-field-values-of-a-list-it):

```
?$select=FileLeafRef
```

There are more [examples on how to retrieve and work with SharePoint ListItems using REST](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2013/09/05/working-with-sharepoint-list-data-odata-rest-and-javascript.aspx) in the MS TechNet  and a good [documentation of the REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx) in MSDN.